# What is the difference between "Improve" and "Improve upon"

Tags: difference

Reading the following sentence:

> The 20th century presented a large number of inventions to advance US society by improving upon the status of 19th-century society

I wonder why it's neccesary to use "upon" next to "improve". Why not only use "improve"?

The [full context](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/brainstorming/) is:

> For example, if your general assignment is to write about the changes in inventions over time, and your specific thesis claims that “the 20th century presented a large number of inventions to advance US society by improving upon the status of 19th-century society,” you could brainstorm two different lists to ensure you are covering the topic thoroughly and that your thesis will be easy to prove.

Comment: Because in the 20th century it was no longer possible to improve the status of a 19th-century society which by then lay in the past.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- *Improve [X]* means to make X better than X was before.

*Apple improved the iPod by adding a color display.*

---

- *Improve upon [X]* means to make a **new** thing that is related to X but better.

*CD's improved upon vinyl records by providing more capacity in a smaller, more durable format.*

---

- Sample sentence: *“the 20th century presented a large number of inventions to advance US society by improving **upon** the status of 19th-century society.*

The 20th century society is not the 19th century society.  It is a new thing, related to the 19th century society, but better.

Comment: Can I suggest that *"Improved upon [X] means to make something that is related to X but better"* would be slightly clearer if you said *"Improved upon [X] means to make **a new thing** that is related to X but better"*.

Comment: @Lostinfrance Yes!